# any way to use absolute path in python subprocess check_output

Tags: python

new to python, i found that subprocess's check_output runs nicely on Windows but it seems to only run cmds that are in windows PATH env variable.

i can execute the following fine:

```
import sys
from subprocess import check_output

cmd = check_output("ipconfig", shell=True)
print(cmd.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

and ipconfig output is displayed fine.

if i try run a specific command not in the path and try absolute path i get errors.

```
import sys
from subprocess import check_output

cmd = check_output("c:\\test\\test.exe", shell=True)
print(cmd.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

Is there no way to use an absolute path reference for check_output? i was not finding any..

i even tried changing to that directory..

```
import sys
from subprocess import check_output
import os

os.chdir("c:\\test\\")
cmd = check_output("test.exe", shell=True)
print(cmd.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

but i get the following error

```
File "C:\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'naviseccli.exe' returned non-zero exit status 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Apparently you managed to execute `naviseccli.exe` just fine, but it returned with non-zero exit status, which causes the `CalledProcessError` (which is the expected behaviour of [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)).

Comment: What errors do you get exactly when you do `check_output("c:\\test\\test.exe", shell=True)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) offers a 'cwd' argument, that will execute in the defined directory:

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen('test.exe', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd='C:/test', shell=True)

out, err = cmd.communicate()
print (out)
```

Using check_output:

```
subprocess.check_output('cd C:/windows && notepad.exe', shell=True)
```

Comment: PERFECT ! thx , this got me what i wanted. i moved from .Net to python so it's such a diff world between the 2 LOL

Comment: I would expect an absolute path to an executable to always work, no matter what the current working directory is. Is this not the case in Python?

Comment: @mihca: Full path is always the best option.

Comment: Yes it works with absolute paths. But one has to use backslashes on Windows when combined with `subprocess.run`. Most Python API can handle forward and backward slahes (e.g. `path.exsists`), but apparently `subprocess.run` not. This was my issue.

Comment: Actually you can use forward slashes on Windows. All of the Windows API call handle them just fine. Subprocess.run works fine with forward slashes. What doesn't work is adding shell=True if your COMSPEC environment variable is set to the default cmd.exe. Powershell also accepts forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about the documentation of [`CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError).

You can examine the output by catching this exception in a `try ... except` block and using the exception instance's `output` attribute.

```
try:
    ... ...                       # Running the command.
except CalledProcessError as cmderr:
    print (cmderr.output)         # Example of using the output.
```

In this way you can examine the failed command's exit status and output.  I don't know what triggered the exact error, but it's unlikely a result of using the absolute path.